# if TD has an ID, which is the fastest way to retrieve it with jQuery

Tags: jquery, performance

OK, pedants, I've edited the question to include the word "directly".  My question is whether there's any performance advantage to filtering on the table/tbody or going directly by id. You should really not assume stupidity in the first instance and give the questioner the benefit of the doubt.

Assuming that using raw javascript *directly* is not allowed, if the TD has an id, e.g. "A17", which is the quickest way to get it using jQuery:

```
   var cell$ = $("#mytable tbody").find("TD#" + id);
```

or

```
   var cell$ = $(id);
```

or something else?

Comment: "Assuming that using raw javascript is not allowed" Assuming you are using jquery, how it could be?

Comment: I love these meaningless (practically speaking) performance questions that impose completely contrived and unrealistic restrictions for their own sake. What A. Wolff said - the restriction given here doesn't even work since jQuery is going to call the native methods for you anyway, making it unavoidable.

Comment: IDs must be unique on context page, so: `$('#'+id)`

Comment: http://jsperf.com/jqselect123

Comment: BoltClock: `jQuery is going to call the native methods for you anyway`. You have misunderstood the question. I am asking if there is a performance difference between fetching the value by its ID through jQuery, or fetching it via the table id through jQuery; I am NOT asking if there is a difference between jQuery and the native methods!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the element directly is the best approach, as this tests suggest (it's actually about 80% faster):

http://jsperf.com/jqselect123

Comment: Thank for for the helpful answer and pointer to that resource, Cristi Pufu.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming raw JS is not allowed, jQuery doesn't work and there is not way what so ever to select a `td` of any `ID`.

Comment: I think it's a silly answer. One should give the questioner the benefit of the doubt. I know that jQuery uses raw javascript.

Comment: We're talking about programming languages, sorry for taking it too `literal`ly.

Comment: No problem, Jakub. It's actually quite funny when I think about it.